# React - Router : Can't access a nested route

Tags: javascript, redux

I have simple movie app with a home page and a watchlist page.
This is how I would like to structure it:

- Home

  - /movie/id
- Watchlist

  - watchlist/movie/id

I would like to access the `movie/id` from both the home page and the watchlist. Right now I can access it but the problem is when I open a movie when I'm on watchlist page it goes back to home and opens it from there, instead of staying on watchlist and opening it from there. I'm using React-Router v5.2. What should I write differently in the route? I tried `/watchlist/movie/:id` but then it didn't render the movie at all, only from Home.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App' style={{ overflowX: 'hidden' }}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={['/movie/:id', '/']}>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={['/movie/:id', '/watchlist']}>
          <Watchlist />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And that's the link for the movie page:

```
 <Link to={`/movie/${id} `}>
 </Link>
```

Comment: why not just create a dedicated route `/watchlist/movie/:id`?

Comment: @AdityaParab I tried that but then  it didn't render the movies when on watchlist page

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the react router tries to match the first url and it is inside switch that will tell to render only one component , you need to remove switch , also donot forget to use BrowserRouter wrapper , as i donot see it in code

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App' style={{ overflowX: 'hidden' }}>
      <GlobalStyles />
     
        <Route exact path={['/movie/:id', '/']}>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={['/movie/:id', '/watchlist']}>
          <Watchlist />
        </Route>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the issue seems to be something else.

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the docs and rearranged my code, which fixed it. And used history.goBack() to go back from wherever it was opened.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged my code the following way which fixed it. According to docs the more specific path like: `/watchlist/movie/:id` should come before the less specific path=`"/watchtlist"`.

```
 <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/watchlist/movie/:id'>
          <MovieDetail pathId={pathId} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/watchlist'>
          <Watchlist />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/movie/:id'>
          <MovieDetail pathId={pathId} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          <Home />
        </Route>
 </Switch>
```